# Steps to install Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, redhat

I have Hadoop configured in my REDHAT system. I am getting the following error when $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive is executed..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)
```

Comment: Following the tutorial from   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hive uses  a 'metastore';  it creates this directory when you invoke it for the first time.  The meta-directory is usually created in the current working directory you are in (i.e. where you are running the hive command)

which dir are you invoking hive command from? Do you have write permissions there?

try this:

```
   cd   <--- this will take you to your home dir (you will have write permissions there)
   hive
```

Comment: @Sujee-Thanks. But getting the following error :- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFJSONTuple.<clinit>(GenericUDTFJSONTuple.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)